# Get terms related to custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am building a site based on categories of information given to each US state.  I have created a taxonomy called state_data and a custom post type for each state. The state post types share the taxonomy, but not all states will get all terms.  I am looking for a way to list all the terms related only to specific states.  The native wp function get_terms gets all the terms for the taxonomy.  Is there a way to filter get_terms by post_type?

Comment: Is't this too complicated design? You have 50 unique post_types? Is't it better to have one post_type, say 'state', and one taxonomy state_data?

Comment: I'm using the post types for multiple things.  For example, I'm using them to pull in RSS feeds from a sister site, and I have no control over taging in that site.  It also has to conform to the organization already designed for the accompanying app.  Trust me, I searched for a better way.

Answer (score 2):

All right thou. If there are not so many entities in each post_type representing state. Say 10 is ok. You can loop for all entities in one post_type and use loop of wp_get_post_terms result to note all term ids and marge it in array.

I'm not so experienced in SQL as I would like to be, but when looking to database, this could be reachable by custom SQL query.

Look, each entity of specific custom post type has unique ID. You can

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'Alabama';
```

Now you have all ID's of entities from Alabama. Now you can select all terms assigned to these entities.

```
SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationship WHERE object_id IN ( *RESULT FROM PREVIOUS QUERY* );
```

So now you've got term_taxonomy_ids related to all Alabama entities and you can get them from wp_term_taxonomy table

```
SELECT term_id from wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id in ( *RESULT FROM PREVIOUS QUERY* );
```

And finaly, you can get all terms from wp_terms or query them by PHP function. As i said. I'm not SQL expert, so I can not get this together by one SQL query, but I would't be so compliacated to put it all together with a little help of PHP. But what matters is efficiency, I guess...

Comment: it is better if someone simplify the 3 lines query.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something like this:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, tr.term_taxonomy_id, t.`name` 
FROM wp_term_relationships as tr 
JOIN wp_posts AS p ON p.ID = tr.`object_Id`
JOIN wp_terms AS t ON t.`term_id` = tr.`term_taxonomy_id`
WHERE p.post_type = 'state_data'
AND t.`name` = 'Alabama'
ORDER BY p.ID;
```

You can select what you want to from the `SELECT` query... just ID, or whatever fields you wish.

Essentially, what the query is doing is linking up the terms table to the posts table through the terms_relationship table.